# I'm new to c++ can you explain pointers in this instance

Tags: c++, pointers

Why does line 18 `Node* bob = new();` not give me an error while line 22 node `actualValue = new Node;` does.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
    Node* node;
public:
    int data;
};

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    int a = 200;
    int* ptr = &a;

    cout << a << " pointer is " << ptr << endl;

    Node* bob = new Node();
    bob->data = 1;


    Node actualValue = new Node;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does line 18 Node* bob = new(); not give me an error while line 22 node actualValue = new Node; does

The line in question is

```
Node actualValue = new Node;
```

`new Node` returns a pointer, you can't assign it to an instance of the `Node` class. And you forgot your parantheses after `new Node` to call the constructor. The correct code is

```
Node *actualValue = new Node();
```

Comment: You don't need the parens. It's "correct" without them.

Comment: `Node` is a POD and calling `new` on it without parentheses is different than with. Feel free to reference the C++ standard on this, but please refrain from editing correct answers with incorrect information, I'll keep rolling it back.

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch to say that this code is more correct though.

Comment: More correct than what, OP's line that doesn't compile? I don't think it's a stretch, but feel free to downvote if you think I'm incorrect and move on.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about what you think "calling the constructor" on this POD `Node` would do? And how that differs from what you get with just `new Node`?

Comment: Also, consider acting a tad less hostile towards people who are trying to help you to learn and to improve your answer, on their own time.

Comment: You're not helping me learn anything (nor did I ask you to), apparently I'm helping you learn. As to your question, `new Node()` will zero-initialize the resulting object, while `new Node` will leave it filled with whatever garbage happens to be in memory. Again, I will recommend reading the C++ standard.

Comment: Okay, looks like I won't get any pleasant discourse from you. I shall abide by your wishes by downvoting the incorrect claim, and moving on. Cheers.

Comment: So to be clear, if I don't put the brackets it will be filled with whatever value is in memory?

Comment: Yes, or more specifically it won't be filled with anything, according to the standard. gcc specifically likes to 0-initialize values, but msvc won't, so be careful.

Comment: a way to get around this quantum "will it be initialized? won't it?" problem is to add a constructor, which will make your structure no longer be POD, and both forms will call your constructor to initialize it. Which is why you should always add a constructor to your classes unless you're absolutely certain the performance gain from not zero-initializing a field is worth the risk.

Comment: ohhh Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

`Node* bob = new Node();` don't give error because `new Node()` returns a pointer `Node*` and the type of `bob` is also `Node*`. You can do assignments between pointers having same types.

`Node actualValue = new Node;` give error because the type of `actualValue` is `Node` and the class `Node` doesn't have any constructors that accept the pointer `Node*`.

Comment: Thank you! this makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ when you declare a new instance of a class,  you can skip the brackets if the constructor has no arguments.

However, this line

```
Node actualValue = new Node;
```

is incorrect as the actualValue variable is decalred in the stack, not in the heap. You can only use new operator with the pointer declarations.

Answer (score 2):

You must come from another language or be a complete beginner, but that's not a problem. I'm here to help you.

In C++, you can create a stack, and a heap variable. The differences are here:

```
int stack_var = 5;
int* heap_var = new int;
*heap_var = 5;
```

The big difference is that a heap variable is allocated with the **new** keyword. You must also know, that stack variables are freed automatically, when the scope ends (basically when you reach the first '}' after the allocation). But you have to delete the heap variables like this:

```
delete heap_var;
```

This will free up the memory. The main problem you have is that calling **new** returns a pointer. A pointer is basically a memory address. A pointer is basically the declared the same as an object, but we add an asterix (*). Like this:

```
Someobject object;
Someobject* pointer;
```

So to wrap it up, you must modify the code like this:

```
Node* bob = new Node();
bob->data = 1;

Node actualValue;

//This is also important!!!
delete bob;
```

Or this:

```
Node* actualValue = new Node();

delete actualValue;
```

I didn't mention it, but it may not be trivial for a beginner: once you **delete** some memory, you can't access it anymore.

Another difference between stack and heap variables:

You access members of a stack object with a dot (.) operator (`stack_obj.foo = 5`), while in case of pointers, with the arrow (->) operator (`pointer->foo = 5`)

Hope it cleared it :D

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to C++ my main languages are java and python so the pointers were a bit tricky to understand. Thanks for clearing my misunderstanding up.

Comment: No problem man! Yeah in those languages it's abstracted away so you can just write code, in C++, you'll get to learn low level stuff, but it's interesting. So keep up the good work!